# How to create dynamic subdomains in React and Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, django-rest-framework, dns

How would I go about creating dynamic subdomains, and having different data on each subdomain, but the same application using React and Nginx.

I want to have an application where foo.com is one part of the React app, let's say an admin dashboard where you can add multiple users.

Then on the bar.foo.com, the bar would be the name of the user and it would serve their little dashboard with data that is for them.

Subsequently, another user goes to baz.foo.com, where baz is the name of the user and he also gets a little dashboard but with data for them.

Also, if a user does not exist for example bar does not exist, the bar.foo.com should return 404.

I want all of these sections in one React / Backend project but for it to serve different parts of the application according to subdomain/domain.

As for the UI and what serves what, foo.com should serve component A, while bar.foo.com and baz.foo.com should serve component B but with different data fetched from the backend.

Comment: Are you giving an assignments here? Your post does not contain question marks so it does not appear to be a question. Nor does it have any code samples that you seek to debug.

Comment: The question was in the title: "How to create dynamic subdomains in React and Nginx". It does not have any code samples because the question is about mainly web server configuration and React code is not really relevant. Plus, I don't know where to start with the dynamic subdomains, I can add a basic server config block of Nginx of a reverse proxy to my React app, but I don't see how thar would be helpful. Best regards.